# How to edit apalike style to show the year at the end?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

In `apalike` style, year appears just after author names:

`[Doe, 2016] Doe, J. (2016). some article. Name of journal.`

How to edit it so that year appears at the end (without parentheses)? i.e. sth like this:

`[Doe, 2016] Doe, J. some article. Name of journal, 2016.`

**Edit:**
Suppose reference.bib includes:

```
@article{Auth123,
    author  = "A. Auth1 and B. Auth2 and C. Auth3",
    title   = "title",
    journal = "journal",
    year    = "2016"}
```

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{Auth123}
\bibliography{references} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

results in
    [image]

If I chage apalike to plainnat (as suggested in the comments), I will get this:
[image]

This moved the year to the end (which was what I wanted), but it repeated the names of authors which is not good.

If in addition I add `\usepackage{natbib}`, I get this:
[image]

I want sth like the first picture but with year moved to the end.

Comment: Since this format is how APA style works, perhaps you should find a different style instead. The `plainnat` style does this. If you need citations in `( )` pass the `round` option to `natbib` when you load it.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. The only problem now is that when there are more than two authors it shows sth like: [author1 et al.(year) author 1, author2 and author3]. Any fix for this?

Comment: @LoMaPh: Could you post a MWE which shows the problem.

Comment: @Jagath I added MWE.

Comment: @LoMaPh: For this you need to make a local copy of `apalike.bst` and need to edit it. Do you want to do that?

Comment: @Jagath Sure. I made a local copy of `apalike.bst`, and modified some lines but it didn't work. Which parts of it I need to edit exactly?

Comment: @LoMaPh: I tried to answer your question. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement is to have the following output:

```
%[Auth1 et al., 2016] Auth1, A., Auth2, B., and Auth3, C. The article title. My Simple Journal, 16:19–24, 2016.
\bibitem[Auth1 et~al., 2016]{Auth123}
Auth1, A., Auth2, B., and Auth3, C.
\newblock The article title.
\newblock {\em My Simple Journal}, 16:19--24, 2016.
```

instead of:

```
%[Auth1 et al., 2016] Auth1, A., Auth2, B., and Auth3, C. (2016). The article title. My Simple Journal, 16:19–24.
\bibitem[Auth1 et~al., 2016]{Auth123}
Auth1, A., Auth2, B., and Auth3, C. (2016).
\newblock The article title.
\newblock {\em My Simple Journal}, 16:19--24.
```

Before we start editing the `bst` file, we need to rename the file to `apalike-edited.bst`, since the copyright says:

> % Copyright (C) 1988, 2010 Oren Patashnik.
>
> % Unlimited copying and redistribution of this file are permitted as long as
>
> % it is unmodified.  Modifications (and redistribution of modified versions)
>
> % are also permitted, but only if the resulting file is renamed.

The following changes need to be done:

1. In the `FUNCTION {output.year.check}`, change the line `" (" year * extra.label * ")" *` to `", " year * extra.label * "" *`. So the function will now become:

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.year.check}
   { year empty$
       { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
       { write$
         ", " year * extra.label * "" *
         mid.sentence 'output.state :=
       }
     if$
   }
   ```

   If you do not need comma before year and need a full point, then you can change `", " year * extra.label * "" *` to `". " year * extra.label * "" *`. Now one problem is fixed, which is *year without parenthesizes*.
2. Next we need to set the year at the end of reference list. For this we need to go an edit functions which creates various types of reference list like `article`, `book`, `booklet`, `inbook`, `incollection`, `inproceedings`, `manual`, `masterthesis`, `misc`, `phdthesis`, `proceedings`, `techreport` and `unpublished`. I will show how to fix this for `article`. Likewise, you need to fix it for all the above reference types.

Search for `output.year.check` in the function `FUNCTION {article}` and cut that line from there. Place that line just before `fin.entry`. So that the function will now become:

```
    FUNCTION {article}
    { output.bibitem
      format.authors "author" output.check
      author format.key output                              % special for
      new.block
      format.title "title" output.check
      new.block
      crossref missing$
        { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
          format.vol.num.pages output
        }
        { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
          format.pages output
        }
      if$
      new.block
      note output
      output.year.check                                     % apalike
      fin.entry
    }
```

which was earlier:

```
    FUNCTION {article}
    { output.bibitem
      format.authors "author" output.check
      author format.key output                              % special for
      output.year.check                                     % apalike
      new.block
      format.title "title" output.check
      new.block
      crossref missing$
        { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
          format.vol.num.pages output
        }
        { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
          format.pages output
        }
      if$
      new.block
      note output
      fin.entry
    }
```

Repeat this process for all types of references and save the file.

I am assuming you have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Auth123,
    title   = {The Article Title},
    author  = {A. Auth1 and B. Auth2 and C. Auth3},
    journal = {My Simple Journal},
    volume = {16},
    pages = {19--24},
    year    = "2016"}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Auth123}
\bibliography{references} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike-edited}
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Just a minor edit: In the final part when u say "Search for output.year.check in the function FUNCTION {article} and copy it. Place that line just before fin.entry". In fact it is a cut instead of copy. If someone doesn't look at the code provided, they may just copy that line.

Comment: @LoMaPh: Oops! Sorry. I will correct that.